NEXT.JS - Page not load correctly during npm run build
I run npm run build to build new version of my website. After the build finished all is ok, but during build, my page not showing correctly. Console shows that js and css files failed to load.
Next error occurs "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"
I tried to add generateBuildId to next.config.js, tried to add /_next/static location config to nginx configuration but my page still not showing correctly during npm run build.

